# Get full current url thymeleaf with all parameters

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Im using thymeleaf with spring mvc. I want add a language param to change locale. I did it this way:

```
<a th:href="@{${currentUrl}(lang='es_ES')}" th:if="__${#locale}__ != 'es_ES'" >Sp</a>
<a th:href="@{${currentUrl}(lang='en_US')}" th:if="__${#locale}__ != 'en_US'" >Eng</a>
```

But in some views I have params in the URL. How I can add the parameters?
I know how to add when I meet the specific parameter:

```
<a th:href="@{${currentUrl}(fooParam = ${fooValue}, lang='es_ES')}" th:if="__${#locale}__ != 'es_ES'" >Sp</a>
```

But I know neither the number and name of all parameters in all views. How I can get all the parameters of the current url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create an utility service for building the params part of your URL. The utility method will get input from a List and build a String through StringBuffer. The result will be a String written as when you write param manually. Now you can use the Pre-Parser syntax built in thymeleaf to call the utility and build your final url.
Here the example:

Utility Service

```
@Service("thymeleafUtilsService")
public class ThymeleafUtilsService
{

    public String buildMultiParamPartUrl(List<String> paramNames)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(0);

        for ( String paramName : paramNames )
        {
            if ( sb.length() >= 0 )
            {
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(paramName).append("=${").append(paramName).append("}");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Controller for testing it

```
@Controller("multiParamLinkController")
@RequestMapping(value = "/multiParamLink")
public class MultiParamLinkController
{

    @RequestMapping(value =
    { "/",
      "" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testMultiParamsGenerator(Model model)
    {
        List<String> paramNames = new ArrayList<>();
        paramNames.add("fooValue");
        paramNames.add("barValue");
        paramNames.add("lang");

        model.addAttribute("fooValue", "foo");
        model.addAttribute("barValue", "bar");
        model.addAttribute("lang", "US_us");

        model.addAttribute("paramNames", paramNames);

        return "multiParamLink/multiParamLink.html";
    }

}
```

HtmlTemplate for Test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <a th:href="@{${currentUrl}(__${@thymeleafUtilsService.buildMultiParamPartUrl(paramNames)}__)}">myLink</a>
  <h1>Result</h1>
  <pre th:inline="text">[[@{${currentUrl}(__${@thymeleafUtilsService.buildMultiParamPartUrl(paramNames)}__)}]]</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

this is what you get with the example:

[image]

You can now customize this example to suit your code, like parsing a Map instead of List or String...

Comment: Thanks, but I solve my problem with a custom decorator for language menú. I make a url with custom params in a java class too. Your solution is simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a *thymeleaf template only version*, you can use  `${#request.getRequestURI()}` with `${#request.getQueryString()}` and add your additional parameters via concatenation:

```html
<a th:href="@{${url}}" th:with="url=${#request.getRequestURI()+'?'+#request.getQueryString()+'&foo=bar'}">Link</a>
```

For more details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75103428/2590616